# Calculate velocity to hit the target on flat 2d surface

Tags: pygame, trajectory

I am creating a game using Python and Pygame.

I have used this function before (with JS with p5.js and Java with libwjgl, but for some reason it does not work with pygame (I am not sure if it matters here).

I'm trying to hit a static target shot from a moving object.
[image]
This is how I am doing this:

```
def shoot(self):
  posX, posY = 100, 100 # Static target coordinates

  diffX = self.player.x - posX               
  diffY = self.player.y - posY                 

  distance = math.sqrt((diffX * diffX) + (diffY * diffY)) # Calculate the distance

  velX = float((-1 / distance * diffX * 6))
  velY = float((-1 / distance * diffY * 6))  

  # Bullet(x, y, width, height, velocityX, velocityY)
  # Will be rendered on the screen
  self.bullets.append(Bullet(self.player.x, self.player.y, 10, 10,  velX, velY))
```

Updating bullet location:

```
  def update(self):
    self.bullet.x += self.velX
    self.bullet.y += self.velY
```

This works perfectly with other languages I have mentioned, but in Python the launched projectile is off...

Here is how it looks. The red square is the target.

THANK YOU, EVERYONE, FOR THE HELP. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: What doesn't work about it? What do you expect to happen and what goes wrong?

Comment: @Jay just because a question doesn't outright say what the problem is, it doesn't mean you can't tell. He's trying to shoot the red square. Based on the gif, it's obviously not going in the right direction. I'll also add that it clearly says that "the projectile is off" so please read the questions

Comment: @Mantas try printing the player position and the velX velY values every frame and post the results

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to help, too. I was confused because I can see two red squares and a yellow circle. Also in the question it is about the direction of the projectile being off and not the position of the square (if that is the target).

Comment: Already solved! Got my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55008954/calculate-x-and-y-velocity-to-hit-the-target-on-flat-2d-surface-in-pygame